# Laravel validation error view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got two different forms on a single page in Laravel.
It's the registration page which has both registration and login form. When I get errors on the registration form, the same errors comes on the login form (see picture). What would be the best way to solve this?

Directly under my forms I use `@include('errors.common')` to display validation errors.

[image]

Comment: Pictures are great and all, but without having snippets of your code, it is hard to say what is going wrong. Seems like you need to find a way to separate your validation rules between the two forms. Each time you are submitting a form from this view, they are using the same validation rules.

Comment: Here is the errors.common view.
http://pastebin.com/R8XZjpVW

It is included under both login and registration form.

I use the default authentication methods that comes with Laravel.

Comment: Again, it has nothing to do with your blade template for errors. What action are your two forms using? Should be withing the opening form tag `<form action="__HERE__" method="POST".....>`

Comment: Oh, sorry.
The registration form uses the same page `/auth/register`, and the login form uses `/auth/login` but they both do `return() -> back()` when they fail. I have tried to get the login form to redirect to the frontpage `/home` on errors, but it won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views

> **Named Error Bags**
>
> If you have multiple forms on a single page, you may wish to name the MessageBag of errors. This will allow you to retrieve the error messages for a specific form. Simply pass a name as the second argument to withErrors:
>
> ```
> return redirect('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
> ```
>
> You may then access the named MessageBag instance from the $errors variable:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $errors->login->first('email'); ?>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

When the validation fails in the controller, you must indicate in the redirect if it was the login or registration that failed:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('loginFail', true);
```

Now in your view where you have your login and registration form, load `@include('errors.common')` accordingly:

```
@if(Session::has('loginFail')
    @include('errors.common')
@endif
```

Use the same principle for the registration form.

Comment: I see. But I don't use my own controller for the login or registration process, so where would I put the `->with...`?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you are using the `AuthController.php` shipped with `Laravel`.

In the **registration form** add a hidden field with the name of `register` with a value of `1`.

In the **login form** add a hidden field with the name of `login` with a value of `1`.

Now you can control when to display the errors like this:

```
// Registration
@if(!$errors->isEmpty())
    @if(!empty(old('register')))
        @include('errors.common')
    @endif
@endif

// Login
@if(!$errors->isEmpty())
    @if(!empty(old('login)))
        @include('errors.common')
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: I've update this answer. This should meet your requirements.